# BIP 84, BIP 173 Implementation in BitcoinJ

Tags: segregated-witness, bitcoinj, p2wpkh

Can BitcoinJ (Java) supports complete implementations of BIP 173, BIP 84?
How can segwit address can be created using BitcoinJ for SPV wallet?

Answer (score 2):

i don't think bitcoinj support BIP-173 but you can read more from 
[Bitcoinj](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj) repo

**For Segwit**
 Bitconj 0.14 branch is ~2 years old and has got no support for segwit at
all. For receiving on native Segwit addresses, you can use the master
branch. For receiving on P2WPKH-P2SH, I'm not sure. If master doesn't
work you can try the segwit branch (but that one isn't tested well).

> Warning: master currently has no support for spending segwit outputs.
>   So only use testnet or really small amounts for now.